# How to allocate array dynamically

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

In this code i am opening a directory and creating an array of elements present in that directory so for that i have to first check number of element(arr_len) present in that directory so that i can give my array that size. And after this i am creating an `arr[arr_len]` like this. I want to dynamically give memory according to number of elements present in directory. using malloc,  calloc, realloc or anything else.

```
DIR *dr = opendir("/path/");
if (dr == NULL) {
     printf("Could not open current directory" );
     return 0;
}
closedir(dr);

DIR *dr_ = opendir("/path/");
if (dr_ == NULL)    {
     printf("Could not open current directory" );
     return 0;
}

int i=0;
int arr[arr_len];
json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object();
while ((de = readdir(dr_)) != NULL){
     if ((strcmp(de->d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(de->d_name, "..") != 0)){
         char file_name[50];
         strcpy(file_name, de->d_name);
         char *strarr[10];
         unsigned char *token = strtok(file_name, "-");
         int j =0;
         while (token!=NULL){
               strarr[j++] = token;
               token = strtok(NULL, "-");
         }
         int val = atoi(strarr[1]);
         arr[i] = val;
         i++;
         json_object_object_add(jobj, strarr[1], json_object_new_string(de->d_name));
    }
}
closedir(dr_);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `realloc()`. The typical usage would be:

```
int arr_size = 0;
int *arr = NULL;

// extending by 1 element

int *new_arr = realloc(arr, (arr_size + 1) * sizeof *new_arr);
if (!new_arr) { ... error handling ... }
arr = new_arr;
arr[arr_size++] = ...
```

If the program is expected to critically fail on failure of `realloc()` then you could simplify the program by omitting `new_arr`.

```
arr = realloc(arr, (arr_size + 1) * sizeof *arr);
if (!arr) { ... error message and exit program ... }
```

Comment: If `realloc` fails, the old data pointed to by `arr` is lost forever.

Comment: @Zakk, by "error handling" I mean clearing all resources like opened files, threads, memory, including data pointed by "arr". Moreover, there might be cases when freeing "arr" may not be necessary

Comment: _"including data pointed by "arr""_ But it is lost, how can you clear it?

Comment: @Zakk, are referring to "arr = realloc(...)" or to "new_arr = realloc(...)" ?

Comment: @Zakk, if `new_arr = realloc(...)` fails then `arr` is still *valid* inside `{ ... error handling ...}` block. You can free it there.

Comment: @tstanisl can we will be able to check size of arr in last (after allocating )? by using `` sizeof(arr)``  because i am doing it but result is coming wrong. just asking for general knowledge

Comment: @DeepankDhillon, No. The `sizeof` is inferred from the type of the operand which is `int*` in this case. Therefore it will return a constant, 4 or 8 depending if your platform is 32 or 64 bits respectively. If `arr` was declared as `int arr[10]` then its type would be `int[10]` and sizeof would return the `10*sizeof(int)`